# Entropy Deprivation on Bind / Named Servers

Tags: linux, bind

I noticed that my DNS servers are having low points in the available entropy:

[image]

(Note it doesn't stay that low, but within 10 minutes there are several low points (this graph shows the min of 10 min windows)). I see that bind does use /dev/random since 9.2.

1. What is bind using entropy for?
2. Are dips in entropy really worth worrying about in the case of bind (would impact user DNS response time for our users)? (I can't think of anything else on the server that would likely end up being blocked on /dev/random).

Comment: Is it doing recursion, or just authoritative?  The cache poisoning avoidance by randomizing the transaction ID and source port comes to mind, but that would just be for recursive queries.

Comment: @ShaneMadden: Just authoritative

Comment: Much traffic? Initiating TCP connections eats up entropy, and DNS uses lots of short TCP bursts for larger answers. Have you compared to other machines with similar loads? Any possibility of fitting a RNG to the machine (or configure the kernel to use the one in newish CPUs)?

Comment: @vonbrand: Don't see a correlation between entropy and packets per second. Would like to understand the cause more before getting into way to generate more entropy.

Comment: More *TCP connections initiated* means more entropy consumed.

Comment: @vonbrand: Ah thanks for the emphasis, I'll look into that

Answer (score 1):

Among other things (as mentioned in the comments), lacking entropy can impact SSL performance (if that's an issue on that server, of course).

There is [software](http://www.issihosts.com/haveged/) available to boost the available entropy considerably.

Comment: [`rngd`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gkernel/) is another option, which to me comes across as less controversial. In particular on modern Intel machines the [RDRAND](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-digital-random-number-generator-drng-software-implementation-guide) support is very convenient. http://lwn.net/Articles/525459/ is a good read, too.